# clean urls in wordpress using nextgen gallery plugin

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, nextgen-gallery

Im using the NextGEN Gallery Plugin. Currently i'm getting the category id by **mysite.com/photography?cat=weddings**

In my page.php, I get the category thats in the url and populate the page based of the category.

```
$cat = $_GET['cat'];
if($cat == 'portraits'){ $cat = 'where galleryid = 5'; }
if($cat == 'weddings'){ $cat = 'where galleryid = 3'; }
if($cat == 'outdoor'){ $cat = 'where galleryid = 4'; }

$q = $wpdb->get_results("
   select filename, meta_data, galleryid, gal.name, pid
   from wp_ngg_pictures as pic
   join wp_ngg_gallery as gal on (gal.gid = pic.galleryid)
   {$cat}
");
```

I want to just do this **/mysite.com/photography/weddings**
and have no query string in the URL. I also would rather not do all these if statements to grab the ID. I dont want the ID to be in the URL at all so I want a good readable url.

Does wordpress have an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `functions.php` to add a new rewrite rule:

```
function my_add_rewrites() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->add_rule('photography/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?pagename=photography&photocat=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_add_rewrites' );

function my_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'photocat';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_query_vars' );
```

Then in your `page.php`, add:

```
global $wp, $wpdb;
// Get the query var
$photocat = $wp->query_vars['photocat'];
// Get the gallery ID
$gid = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT gid FROM $wpdb->ngg_gallery WHERE slug = '$photocat';" );
// Check if we have a valid value
$q = FALSE; // Set a default so you can check later
if( $gid !== NULL ) {
    // Get the images -> could also use $nggdb->get_gallery($gid);
    $q = $wpdb->get_results("
        select filename, meta_data, galleryid, gal.name, pid
        from wp_ngg_pictures as pic
        join wp_ngg_gallery as gal on (gal.gid = pic.galleryid)
        {$gid}
    ");
}
```

You should also be able to get your images from a gallery via `$nggdb->get_gallery($gid)` which may be easier & cleaner.

Once you have added all the (rewrite) code, go to `Settings -> Permalinks` and re-save your permalink settings to add the new rewrite rule to the DB.

`mysite.com/photography/weddings` should now set the `$photocat` variable to `weddings` and pull your images from that gallery.